# Using tagged_places API call

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have one question related with using tagged_places API call. That call is approved for my FB application (application is reviewed and approved), but I still can get tagged_places only for my account (app administrator), for every other (authorized) user api returns empty array.

this is URL I call: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me/tagged_places?access_token=XXXX&format=json&method=get&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1

I have to mention App is approved today, is there maybe some time period that I need to wait before I can start using tagged_places function?

thanks

---

small update, when I validate my token (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken?q=XXX), and token of other users there is difference in scopes. On scopes list for my token is user_tagged_places, but for other users that scope missing :S That's weird because we are all using the same login url

Comment: Did you send the other users through the login flow again, _after_ the permission was approved by FB? Are they asked for the permission in the login dialog that shows up?

Comment: Yes I did, actually I just found the problem. My website was using old facebook sdk, and login didn't going through https://www.facebook.com/v2.1/dialog/oauth, there was url without v2.1 version

Answer (score 3):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27130806/facebook-graph-api-tagged-places-returns-empty-array/27233145#27233145) solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

"I have had a similar issue and it wasnt the read_stream permission I needed. So I went through permissions in groups testing them out and I figured out what the problem was. You need to have the permission of the item you were tagged in. So in my case I was tagged in photos, so I needed user_photos permission to gain access to user_tagged_places. You were obviously tagged in someones post on their stream so you needed that permission. It actually creates quite an issue because you need to know how a user was tagged to retrieve their tagged_places."

[This Answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27130806/facebook-graph-api-tagged-places-returns-empty-array/27233145#27233145)