# Facebook Graph API tagged_places returns empty array

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to get a users *tagged_places* but the array always comes back empty. If I go through the Graph explorer and generate a token then I get the results as expected but using an access token generated in my application I get returned an empty array.
I am requesting the *user_tagged_places* permission, I know that my app will have to go for review because of this permission requirement but I am just testing right now with my own developer account and test users but it doesn't work for any of them. Will I be able to get the data prior to sending my app for review?
Thanks in advance for the help.
EDIT:
Here's the request

```
function get_fb_tagged_places($session, $uid)
{
    $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/'.$uid.'/tagged_places');
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
    $events_array = $graphObject->asArray();
    return $events_array;
}
```

UPDATE:
Just to be sure I added every permission to my app and it now works! To save me the hassle of removing permissions until I figure it out, does anybody know exactly which permissions are needed to get *tagged_places*? I assumed that *user_tagged_places* was all that was needed because that's all the SDK guide mentions but obviously there are other permissions required.

Comment: What's your request look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had a similar issue and it wasnt the `read_stream` permission I needed. So I went through permissions in groups testing them out and I figured out what the problem was. 
You need to have the permission of the item you were tagged in. 
So in my case I was tagged in photos, so I needed `user_photos` permission to gain access to `user_tagged_places`. You were obviously tagged in someones post on their stream so you needed that permission. It actually creates quite an issue because you need to know how a user was tagged to retrieve their tagged_places.

Comment: That poses a real problem because for the Facebook review process (which you will need to go through if you require more than the standard permissions) you need to give an explanation as to why you need each permission. You may not be able to think of every possible permission however and if you need to add a permission at a later date then you will have to go through the review process again. Also I'm not sure if they allow the requesting of permissions that you won't definitely need.

Comment: Yeah - were going through that process at the moment. It does seem ridiculous, that if you request tagged places, that you also need other permissions for them. If I find any further information out I will post it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: It was pointed out that read_stream is not what is required, it is whatever the user was tagged in.

Found the answer in the end, the permission: *read_stream* also seem to be required in order to see a users *tagged_places* however I did not see this mentioned in the docs anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The way i worked around this was by querying for photos first and then its place.

```
me?fields=id,name,photos.limit(10){place}
```